# PHP Namespace, why still use suffix?

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces

The current version PHP i use version 5.5.x. It is support namespace, but i still see some Framework like Symfony2 still using suffix in their class name.

e.g: For controller it have suffix Controller: AdminController, UserController

**Is that a good practice still using suffix?** i mean, we didn't need to afraid of name collision since there's already a namespace.

Comment: Surely namespaces make *pre*fixes redundant. I wouldn't see `Controller` so much as a suffix as part of the name of the class...

Comment: I use the same pattern for interfaces and abstract classes too: `class UserInterface` or `class UserAbstract`

Comment: Does the name Admin by itself tell you anything? Admin or User here is an adjective, while Controller is a noun.  These probably have a common base class named Controller - This is a very common OOP naming convention.

Comment: @feela as a C# developer, I would call those IUser and UserBase, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in some cases it's useful to add suffixes.
For example when you import class

```
use My\Namespace\Controller\NewsController;
```

and use it later

```
$newsController = new NewsController()
```

you see that it is controller and not some POPO class. However you also can import package with it's own name like

```
use My\Namespace\Controller as Controller
```

ans use it in code as

```
$newsController = new Controller\News()
```

but as for me it's harder to read and understand

Comment: oh i see, `$newsController = new Controller\News() ` is sure harder to read.

Comment: Of course you also can use $newsController = new News(), but in that case it's completely not understandable what class you use (maybe you also have News as entity, News as parser, etc)